# Send Message When Animation Progress

Tags: ios, animation, swift, uiview

I thought this question would be already answered, but I didn't find anything in Apple's documentation and elsewhere. Maybe I'm searching using wrong words.

I animate a UIView with `UIView.animateWithDuration(...)`, and I want to send a message each time the animation state changed.

For example :

```
var subview:UIView?

func animation() {

    subview = UIView(frame:oldFrame)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {

        subview.frame = newFrame

    }, completion:nil)

}
```

I want to print the frame each time it changes, and not only one time (which is the case actually).

I tried using property observers, but using willSet on my subview doesn't print anything, because only the frame changes.

Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: You need to understand how animations work in iOS. As a starting point, you should know the difference between views and layers. Long story short, it's the presentation layer who's properties are modified while being animated, not the view's.

Comment: @Abizern I'm building a custom control, and I want to send .ValueChanged each time the value changes, to do something in the superview